# Подключение WebSocket4Net к проекту WP8.1

Tags: visual-studio, websocket, windows-phone-8

Как подключить и правильно использовать *WebSocket4Net*?

Больше интересует именно то, как подключить его к проекту *visual studio*, ибо все остальное есть в документации.

Comment: Уточните в чем проблема с подключением к проекту данной библиотеки.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.